# Modifying TCP options in HTTPFlow

Tags: mitmproxy

Is there anyway to add, remove or modify TCP options in a HTTPFlow (via the addon/events api) in mitmproxy?

Comment: What kind of TCP options are you thinking of?

Comment: MSS and Timestamp

Comment: That's not configurable from mitmproxy, sorry.